# How do I write a script that loops through different folders and saves PATH outputs into a tab-delimited text file?

Tags: bash, loops, path

I am a newbie who is attempting to write a script that utilizes a text file containing names of different folders (subj1, subj2, subj3... etc), loops through each folder and goes into these folders to extract **full paths** of two files inside (i.e. /Users/desktop/subj1/animals/pig.jpg, /Users/desktop/subj1/animals/cow.jpg), then saves the subject ID and two files in **3 columns** in a tab-delimited text file. (E.g. subj1  /Users/desktop/subj1/animals/pig.jpg /Users/desktop/subj1/animals/cow.jpg) so on and so forth.

The output would look like:

subj1     /Users/desktop/subj1/animals/pig.jpg /Users/desktop/subj1/animals/cow.jpg 
subj2      /Users/desktop/subj2/animals/pig.jpg /Users/desktop/subj2/animals/cow.jpg

I have tried searching for answers but nothing really came close to answering this query.. I also need to do this for over 1000 folders so it would be insane to try to create a file by hand.

(edit): I would have to first verify if the files exist inside each folder. I created an array using a text file of folder names. Here is what I have thus far:

```
    read -r -a array <<< ${subj_numbs}
    array_error_file=()

    for subj in "${array[@]}"
    do
    echo "Working on.." \"${subj}\"

    pig_file=${dir}/${subj}/animals/pig.jpg
    cow_file=${dir}/${subj}/animals/cow.jpg

    if [ ! -f $pig_file ] && [ ! -f $cow_file ]; then
    echo "    [!] Files ${pig_file} and ${cow_file} do not exist."
    array_error_file+=($pig_file)
    array_error_file+=($cow_file)

    else
    echo "Writing path names to text file.. -> \"${subj}\"
    pig_path="$pig_file"; pwd
    cow_path="$cow_file"; pwd
```

Comment: please show the folder structure by using the command "tree -a". please install tree package if you don't have it

Comment: Do you  know that the files exist in every folder or do you want to check if they exist and then write their full paths? If they exist the task is just to combine strings, no need to go into the folders. If you need to check them - I would use `find` and format the output to your liking.

Comment: @dr_agon I have made changes to my post in order to specify

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
while read line; do
     pig="$(cd "$(dirname "$line/animals/pig.jpg")"; pwd)/$(basename "$line/animals/pig.jpg")"
     cow="$(cd "$(dirname "$line/animals/cow.jpg")"; pwd)/$(basename "$line/animals/cow.jpg")"
     echo "$line \t $pig \t $cow" >> yourtabfile.txt
done < yourlist.txt
```

I'd be glad editing this to make it fitting your situation if it doesn't work, but that means you would have to provide more info.

Comment: Hi @Will, thanks for this suggestion. What I have done so far is to create an array file using the text file with names of the folders, do a 'for' loop to loop through each folder. Within this loop, I would first certify if the files exist. Then if they do, my plan is to get the paths of these files and then write them into separate columns along with the ID of the respective folder. I will edit my original question to make it clearer.

How can I best implement this?